# Apache Camel Dynamic Router

Tags: apache-camel

I would like to know how to do extra control on the **Dynamic Controller**. I have created a dynamic controller with a list of end points to execute. But how can I control the action of the next EndPoint to execute. Is it possible to execute the next route when I receive the message "**CamelBatchComplete=True**" otherwise continue with the current (previous) route.

Comment: Can you please provide java dsl / camel xml for what you are trying to do so far

Comment: I have created a Queue with all the routes to be processed. The route list is the source of the Dynamic Router. The first route is starting with to download several files from a FTP server. Depending of the application is the next route to process these downloaded files and upload these files to another location. The Dynamic Router doesn't wait till the "download" has finished (CamelBatchComplete=true) and continue with the next route from the RouteList till the list is empty and the Dynamic Router receive the null value to stop the routing process.

Comment: show code please